# Lambda layer import error using AWS CDK in Python (same file works fine when uploaded via console)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-layers

I'm encountering an issue with my AWS CDK (v2) Python deployment when attaching a Lambda layer. I have a zipped Lambda layer file structured as follows: python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/. When I upload this zip file manually through the AWS Management Console, my Lambda functions work perfectly fine.

However, when I attempt to attach the same zipped Lambda layer using AWS CDK in Python, I encounter an import error within the Lambda functions that utilize this layer.

Here's part of my CDK setup for the Lambda layer:

```
layer_zip_path = "path/to/my/layer.zip"

my_layer = _lambda.LayerVersion(
    self, "MyLayer",
    code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(layer_zip_path),
    compatible_runtimes=[_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_11]
)
```

I've checked the zip structure, ensured that necessary dependencies are included within site-packages, and confirmed that the runtime specified in CDK matches my Lambda functions' runtime. However, the import error persists when using the CDK-deployed Lambda layer.

Could someone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this discrepancy between manual upload and CDK deployment that leads to the import error?

Any help or guidance on troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Is it *exactly the same* zip file as what is being uploaded? What is the error you get?

Comment: @Ermiya yes, it's exactly same file and when it's deployed using CDK I see in console that my layer is attached to lambda properly but I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError. When I created lambda layer uploading this file using aws console imports works fine.

Comment: Hm... strange. What architecture is your Lambda? x86_64 or arm64? What is the layer using? And can you share the exact error please?

Comment: x86_64 and I set it explicitly also for my lambda layer, although documentation says thats default value when it's not specified.

Comment: And my other questions?

Comment: It's something similar to:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'my_lambda': No module named   ''requests",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}

Comment: Does the code size as reported by the Lambda console match exactly between the two methods (CDK and manual)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved... I didn't provide the path to the actual zip file, only to the directory containing the zip file. That's why my layer didn't work.

Comment: Voting to close the question as "Non-reproducible or was caused by a typo"

Answer (score -1):

Move the shared zip file in the path of your lambda cdk code and try something like this.

```
    code=aws_lambda.AssetCode(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "shared.zip")
    )
```

It would give you the full path to zip file. Since you could be missing the full path to zip file.

Comment: Can you add more details - why would this work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).